# Given the Turing machines M1 and M2, is L (M1) = L (M2)? is decidable?

Tags: turing-machines, undecidability, decision-problem

I thought to reduce from the halting problem to conclude undecidability, yet I don't know how to do it. Perhaps the problem reduces to other decidable problem, and thus it is also decidable?

Comment: It has been a few years since my theory course but if I recall right, that is undecidable. Look into Rice's theorem, it may be useful for this.

Comment: I suggest you keep trying.

Comment: @HankIgoe  
I did it differently as according to you you would by Rice's theorem?

Comment: @Paradojin Here is a demonstration of how it can be done with Rice's theorem, if you're interested: https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/19876/is-it-possible-to-prove-eqtm-is-undecidable-by-the-rice-theorem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you suggested, think how to reduce from the halting problem $Halt_{TM} = \{ \langle M, w\rangle: \text{$M$ halts on $w$} \}$. On input $\langle M, w\rangle$, the reduction should output a pair of TMs $\langle K_1, K_2\rangle$; such that $M$ halts on $w$ iff $L(K_1) = L(K_2)$.

This is somehow a basic reduction that can be done by standard tricks, so it would be a nice exercise to solve it alone. Here is a hint.

**Hint:** you can simplify things by fixing one of the machines $K_1$ or $K_2$ to be a constant machine that recognizes some fixed language. Then, think how to define the other machine depending on the reduction's input $\langle M, w\rangle$.

Comment: thanks this helped me a lot!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad it did help.